# Flexdashboard relaunches my shiny app during resize. All inputs are lost. Is there a way to completely remove the relaunching functionality?......_

Tags: shiny, flexdashboard, responsiveness

Flexdashboard and or underlying libraries cause the app to relaunch obliterating any inputs the user may have entered when the app is resized.  This is likely do to mobile functionality but is a non-starter in many instances.

This needs a flag to disable completely relaunching of server-side content in Shiny.

... this is already a known design flaw in flexdashboard.